# 18.04 with AMD graphics card: black screen on boot, cursor in recovery mode

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics

Since a few days ago my computer is giving me a black screen when I boot it up. At first, I could still start it in recovery mode. All info I could find to fix it points to the graphics driver (in my case for AMD Radeon RX 480).

I tried to reinstall the amdgpu driver, but somehow it seems not to become active when checking: `lsmod | grep -e amdgpu` gives no output. Also `lshw -c video` shows no active driver. I tried with oibaf drivers, but with no effect.
Then I tried setting 'quiet splash nomodeset' in `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. However, after that I can't login in recovery mode anymore either; I now get a quick flashing screen of my desktop background for a few seconds and then a black screen with a cursor. I can still open tty2 with Ctrl+Alt+F2.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I've searched for info, but am a bit lost now.

Answer (score 1):

today I installed Lubuntu 19.04 (x64) on an small EeePC with C6 dual core AMD processor and Radeon HD6290, and I was getting a black screen on every login screen.

Tried the 'nomodeset', but it didn't work.

But I did notice that if I closed the netbook lid, and opened it again, it would go to sleep mode, and then it could be woken up running fine.

It was not really a graphical driver problem, but instead the screen would just change the backlight to an off state at the login screen.

After some searching around, I followed the instructions from here:
https://www.debugpoint.com/2016/10/2-ways-fix-laptop-brightness-problem-ubuntu-linux/

So I opened:
    sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Modified this line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to be: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"

Save the file, close text editor, then run:

sudo update-grub

and reboot.

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. 'nomodeset' was the culprit.
Removing 'nomodeset' from within recovery mode apparently did not register it in the settings. Pressing 'e' to edit '*Ubuntu' in the grub menu solved it and then I could save the change in 'etc/default/grub'.
The computer works fine now with the drivers from the AMD website.